# Do the values in columns have to be unique for JOINs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

For example, if in table A the column "id" is the PRIMARY KEY and in table B, we are guaranteed that the column "id" contains multiple instances of the same value. (and would just like to return the rows from table A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you can join tables regardless of the contents of the columns.

If there is more than matching column, more than one match result will be output.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Any matches will be matched in a JOIN, for instance if you have ColumnA joined with ColumnB and there's 3 matches in ColumnA and 5 in ColumnB, you'll end up with 15 results.

ColumnA
1
2
3
2
3

ColumnB
3
4
3
3
4
3
2

ColumnB and ColumnA will match 15 times.